# NullPointerException while iterating over Binary Tree

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

Now I'm not sure anybody can really help me with this, since it's a pretty sizable amount of code to go through, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my relevant code:

```
public class BTree implements Iterable<String> {
    /** Left child */
    BTree left;
    /** Right Child */
    BTree right;
    /** Comparator to use for sorting */
    Comparator<String> comp;
    /** Parent node */
    BTree parent;
    /** String stored in this leaf */
    String s;
    /** # of iterators currently working on it */
    int active = 0;
    /** Size of the BTree */
    int size;

public void build(Iterable<String> iter, int numStrings) {
        if (this.active > 0) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        } 
        else { 
            Iterator<String> itr = iter.iterator();
            while (numStrings != 0 && itr.hasNext()) {
                String s = itr.next();
                if (!this.contains(s)) {
                    this.insert(s);
                    this.size++;
                    numStrings--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Inserts the string into the given BTree
 * @param str - String to insert
 */
private void insert(String str) {
    if (this.s.equals("")) {
        this.s = str;
    }
    else if (this.comp.compare(str, this.s) > 0) {
        if (this.right == null) {
            BTree bt = BTree.binTree(this.comp);
            bt.s = str;
            this.right = bt;
            bt.parent = this;
        } 
        else {
            this.right.insert(str);
        }
    }
    else if (this.comp.compare(str, this.s) < 0) {
        if (this.left == null) {
            BTree bt = BTree.binTree(this.comp);
            bt.s = str;
            this.left = bt;
            bt.parent = this;
        }
        else {
            this.left.insert(str);
        }
    }
}



  private class BTreeIterator implements Iterator<String> {
            /** Current BTree being iterated over */
            BTree current;
            /** How many next() calls have there been */
            int count;
            /** Size of the BTree */
            int max;
            /** Constructor for BTreeIterator
             * @param current
             */
            BTreeIterator(BTree current) {
                this.current = current;
                this.count = 0;
                this.max = current.size;
                active++;
            }

            /** Returns true if there is another string to iterate over
             * @return boolean
             */
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (this.count != this.max) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    active--;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            /**
             * Returns the next string in the iterator
             * @return String
             */
            public String next() {
                if (this.count == 0) {
                    this.count++;
                    current = this.current.getLeftMost();
                    if (this.current.s.equals("")) {
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    }
                    return this.current.s;
                }
                else if (this.current.right != null) {
                    this.current = this.current.right.getLeftMost();
                    this.count++;
                    return this.current.s;
                }
                else {
                    BTree tree = this.current;
                    while (tree.parent.right == tree) {
                        tree = tree.parent;
                    }
                    this.current = tree.parent;
                    this.count++;
                    return this.current.s;
                }
            }

            /** Throws an exception since we aren't removing anything from the trees
             */
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

        }
    }
```

}

The Exception gets thrown at the `while (tree.parent.right == tree)` line in the next() method of the iterator. The funny thing is, my code has worked just fine with a comparator comparing lexicographically and reverse lexicographically sorting through a file of 24000 words. It only throws the exception when using the following comparator:

```
class StringWithOutPrefixByLex implements Comparator<String> {

/**
 * compares o1 and o2
 * @param o1 first String in comparison
 * @param o2 second String in comparison
 * @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer 
 *         as the first argument is less than, equal to, or 
 *         greater than the second. 
 */
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    String s1, s2;
    if(o1.length() > 4){
        s1 = o1.substring(3);
    }
    else { 
        s1 = o1;
    }
    if(o2.length() > 4){
        s2 = o2.substring(3);
    }
    else { 
        s2 = o2;
    }
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
}
}
```

Even weirder, it works fine with that comparator for the same file up to 199 words, but as soon as I have it build up to 200 words it breaks.

EDIT: I have determined that the Exception is due to the code trying to reference `tree.parent.right` while `tree.parent` is `null`, but I can't figure out WHY it's trying to do that. As far as I can tell, my code should never try to call a null `tree.parent`, as explained by my comment below.

Comment: Add try&catch to the Comparator and print in the catch the values of `o1` & `o2` - so you'll be able to find your "corner case". The only thing that comes into mind is that you don't handle cases where either `o1` or `o2` are `null` (seems like `s1` is somehow `null` and you have a NPE on the last line).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not actually show enough of your code, but, what about the root node of your BTree? What is the value of `BTree.parent` in the root node? `null`?

If the root node has a null parent, then, in this while loop, it is likely that :

```
                while (tree.parent.right == tree) {
                    tree = tree.parent;
                }
```

... will get to the root node, the `tree` will be set to `tree.parent`, which is `null`, and then the while loop test will fail because `tree.parent.right` will attempt to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: The root parent is null, but the code should never reach that point. Either The topmost node has a right child, in which case          `else if (this.current.right != null)` should catch it. If it doesn't have a right child then it should be the last node to be iterated on, and the `hasNext()` should be false, stopping it from attempting to call `tree.parent.`